# Google Earth Engine: Problem with the updateMask function

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, masking

I'm trying to use the updateMask function in GEE but I'm not quite sure how to use it in this occasion. So i did a trend analysis with formaTrend() to analyze the loss of forest cover in an area:

```
  var aoi = ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon([
  [6.753654920661802,49.98597828191218],
  [6.7461018200758645,49.902020897367365],
  [6.941795789802427,49.897598033936816],
  [6.945915662849302,49.99083449205881],
  [6.753654920661802,49.994807390209445],
  [6.753654920661802,49.98597828191218]]);


var addVI = function(image) {
  image = image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']).rename('NDVI'));
  return image;
}

var coll = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA')
  .filterDate('1995-01-01', '1995-12-30') // Zeitraum vor den Sturmereignissen
  .filterBounds(aoi)
  .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUD_COVER', 4))
  .sort('DATE_ACQUIRED')// Collection sortiert nach Cloudcover


var coll2 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA')
  .filterDate('1996-01-01', '1996-12-30') // Zeitraum vor den Sturmereignissen
  .filterBounds(aoi)
  .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUD_COVER', 8))
  .sort('DATE_ACQUIRED')

print(coll, coll2);

var collection = coll.merge(coll2);
collection = collection.map(addVI);

// Forma Trend
var ndvistack = collection.select('NDVI');

var trend = ndvistack.formaTrend();
var ltTrend = trend.select(['long-trend']).clip(aoi);

var loss = ltTrend.mask(ltTrend.lt(0));

Map.addLayer(loss, {color: 'red'}, 'Loss');

var img = collection.median();

// img = img.updateMask(loss); doesnt work ):
```

After I figured out the areas which are affected by loss (stored in there variable "loss"). Now i want to calculate another vegeatation index exclusively on the areas where the algorithm detected a loss.

I tried using the updateMask() function like this:

```
img = img.updateMask(loss);
```

but i think i'm missing something, which i can't find out.
Is there a way to use the loss variable as a mask for other images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Masking should be done on images with zeros and ones. You just have to update the mask as you did previously when obtaining the loss image. A less than or greater than expression are generally used for the input of updateMask.

```
var masked = img.updateMask(ltTrend.lt(0));
```

[Here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/4983c4217c954af2c4e33c88ab12e9d9) is how I adapted your code and added the masked and unmasked median composites to the map.